# Expected value and projection of a normal random variable onto a linear span...?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, projective-geometry

I just wanted to clarify a part of a proof which used the fact a random variable has zero mean.

Suppose $X, Z_{s_1},\dots,Z_{s_n}$ are all jointly normal random variables for all $s_i \leq t$ and $n \geq 1$.

Define $\mathcal{L}(Z,t)$ as set of random variables of the form

$$c_1 Z_{s_1}+ \dots + c_n Z_{s_n}$$

for $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s_i \leq t$, $n \geq 1$, along with all their limit points (in $L^2(P)$).

Define $\tilde{X} = X - \mathcal{P}_L (X)$ where $\mathcal{P}_L$ is the projection onto the space $\mathcal{L}(Z,t)$.

Then the proof use $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}] = 0$.

My understanding of this, is that the projection $\mathcal{P}_L (X)$ coincides with the conditional expectation

$$\mathcal{P}_L (X) = E[X|\mathcal{F}_L]$$

where $\mathcal{F}_L$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by the random variables in $\mathcal{L}(Z,t)$. And hence by law of total expectation we have

$$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}] = \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[E[X|\mathcal{F}_L]] = \mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X] =0$$

Is this correct? The proof doesn't really explain, and the relationship between projection and probability spaces is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: What proof is this? What source?

Comment: It is part of [Oksander's SDE book](http://th.if.uj.edu.pl/~gudowska/dydaktyka/Oksendal.pdf)  lemma 6.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out, it holds that
$$
\mathcal{L}(Z,t) \neq L^2(\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t)).
$$ But if we assume additionally that $$(X,Z_s;s\leq t)$$
is jointly normally distributed, it holds that
$$
P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X = P_{L^2(\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t))}X.
$$ To see this, notice that if $(X,Y_1,\ldots ,Y_n)$ is jointly normal, then
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y_i) = 0,\,\forall i\leq n \Leftrightarrow X\text{ and }(Y_i)_{i\leq n} \text{ are independent.}
$$ It holds that
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X-P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X, Z_s) = 0,\quad\forall s\leq t,
$$ by the definition of the projection. And since $(X,Z_s;s\leq t)$ is jointly normal, so is $(X-P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X,Z_s;s\leq t).$ This implies that
$$
X-P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X  \perp \!\!\! \perp   (Z_s)_{s\leq t}.
$$ Therefore, we have
$$
P_{L^2(\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t))}[X-P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X]=P_{L^2(\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t))}X-P_{\mathcal{L}(Z,t) }X=0,
$$as desired. In your notation, $\mathcal{F}_L=\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t)$ and $P_{L^2(\sigma(Z_s;s\leq t))}X = E[X|\mathcal{F}_L].$

Comment: Can I ask you to take a look at a [question I'm trying to answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584156/what-fraction-of-a-random-gaussian-vector-lies-outside-the-span-of-d-i-i-d-ra) that let me here?

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is not valid. Conditional expectation is the projection on the space of all random variables measurable w.r.t. $\sigma \{Z_s:s\leq t\}$, not the projection on to the vector space spanned by $ \{Z_s:s\leq t\}$. The former space contains many nonlinear functions of $ \{Z_s:s\leq t\}$ like $Z_t^{2}$.